# Copy duplicates and unique to sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I use this codes to separate the duplicates to sheet(dup). Now I want to separate the singles/unique records also to sheet(unique) so from one worksheet there will be two more sheets one of unique records and other of duplicates.

```
Option Explicit 

Sub FindCpy() 
    Dim lw As Long 
    Dim i As Integer 
    Dim sh As Worksheet 

    Set sh = Sheets("Dup") 
    lw = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 

    For i = 1 To lw 'Find duplicates from the list.
        If Application.CountIf(Range("A" & i & ":A" & lw), Range("A" & i).Text) > 1 Then 
            Range("B" & i).Value = 1 
        End If 
    Next i 

    Range("A1:B10000").AutoFilter , Field:=2, Criteria1:=1 
    Range("A2", Range("A65536").End(xlUp)).EntireRow.Copy 
    sh.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
    Selection.AutoFilter 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You can use the following to route unique and duplicate values to different sheets. You can easily modify this code to suit your needs (only display duplicate values once on the duplicate sheet, for example).

```
Sub RouteUniqueAndDuplicateValues()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dupes As Worksheet
    Dim unique As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set dupes = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dupes")
    Set unique = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Unique")

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ws.Range("B1").Formula = "=COUNTIF(A$1:A$" & lastRow & ", A1)"
    ws.Range("B1").Copy ws.Range("B2:B" & lastRow)

    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:B" & lastRow)
    With rng
        ' find dupes
        .AutoFilter , field:=2, Criteria1:=">1"
        ' copy them to our dupes sheet
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dupes.Range("A1")
        ' find unique
        .AutoFilter , field:=2, Criteria1:=1
        ' copy them to our unique sheet
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy unique.Range("A1")
    End With
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```